# How to give an argument to command in Visual Studio Code extension development

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building a VS Code extension.

I follow [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/api).

This is my menu in `package.json` :

```json
{   "contributes": {
 "commands": [
  {
           "command": "demo.Set_A",
        "title": "Set A"      
   }  ,
 {
           "command": "demo.Set_B",
        "title": "Set B"         
   }  ,
 {
        "command": "demo.Set_C",
        "title": "Set C"        
   }  
],
     "menus": {    
   "explorer/context": [     
    {
           "command": "demo.Set_A"      
   }  ,
 {
           "command": "demo.Set_B"      
   }  ,
 {
           "command": "demo.Set_C"      
   }  
     ]   
  }  
 }
}
```

---

This is my `extension.ts` source:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

let disposableA = vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo.Set_A', () => {/* ... */});
let disposableB = vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo.Set_B', () => {/* ... */});
let disposableC = vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo.Set_C', () => {/* ... */});
};
```

---

I want to receive arguments so that my code looks like this.

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo.Set_A', (parameter) => {
switch (parameter) {
            case "A": /* ... */ break;
            case "B": /* ... */ break;
            case "C": /* ... */ break;
        };
});
};
```

How can I do this by changing the `package.json`?

Comment: Format your question properly. This is unreadable

Comment: You want the file or folder that was where the context menu was triggered? Use the version that has the `parameter` argument - it will automatically completed by vscode.